# Crystal Reports Paramteres

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi, saleslogix

My report is working in Crystal Reports designer, but when I am adding it into the Sage Sales logix it doesnt sends the parameter values to database and errors out.

I am using a command like this in the report

```
exec('select * from testingmyreportfunction({?Param1},{?Param2})')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you created the parameters in `command` window use this query:

```
// Oracle
SELECT  testingmyreportfunction({?Param1}, {?Param2}) 
FROM    dual

// SQL Server
SELECT  testingmyreportfunction({?Param1}, {?Param2})
```

Comment: No I am using SQL SERVER 2012